# Cambiar colores al presionar un botón en html5

Tags: html5, css3

tengo un formulario con un botón y lo que quiero lograr es poder cambiar los colores del body, form y label al momento de precionar el botón por ejemplo para el body que sea azul, el form rojo y los label blancos y el button amarillo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Cambiante</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body{background-color: red;}
  form{background-color: yellow;}
  label{color: black;font-style: bold;}
  button{color: white; background-color:green; }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="get" action="#">
  <label>Ingrese su id</label>
  <input type="text" ><br>
  <label>Ingrese su nombre</label>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <label>Ingrese su edad</label>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <button type="button">Ejecutar</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer sencillo con Javascript o un poco más elegante con Sass.

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  const body   = document.querySelector('body'),
        form   = document.querySelector('form');
  body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  form.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  button.style.backgroundColor = 'brown';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Cambiante</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body{background-color: red;}
  form{background-color: yellow;}
  label{color: black;font-style: bold;}
  button{color: white; background-color:green; }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="get" action="#">
  <label>Ingrese su id</label>
  <input type="text" ><br>
  <label>Ingrese su nombre</label>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <label>Ingrese su edad</label>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <button type="button">Ejecutar</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió :)